# Покрытие юнит-тестами

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit, android-testing

Не совсем ясно, нужно ли покрывать тестами все полностью, даже те методы, которые точно не могут сломаться в силу своей простоты, или все же нужно тестировать только логические участки.

Вот для примера метод:

```
private void continuousFromStopPoint(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            startAppReg();
            break;
        case 1:
            startGCMReg();
            break;
        case 2:
            startAppRegUpdate();
            break;
    }
}
```

Он в зависимости от значения вызывает тот или иной метод. И у меня даже идеи нет, как и на что его тестировать.

Или вот такой метод, вроде как поинтереснее:

```
private boolean isWasFinished(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    boolean wasFinished = false;
    try {
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            wasFinished = jsonObject.getBoolean(WAS_FINISHED);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return wasFinished;
}
```

Тут уже можно проверить возвращаемое значение, но опять же, на что его проверять, когда мне без разницы какое значение вернется. Если `true` код выполнит одно, если `false` то другое. На что проверять?

**Подскажите как разобраться?**

Comment: В первом методе как вариант можно тестировать / проверять обработку переданных значений: -1, 0, 100. Правильно ли я понимаю, что при получении таких значений, метод должен ничего не делать?

Comment: @lospejos ну в целом правильно. Все что не относиться к 0, 1, 2 должно игнориться... А можете для примера написать как должен выглядеть такой тест?

Comment: Зачем вы тестируете приватные методы? Не надо так. Так как если у вас правильно работают публичные методы, которые используют приватные, значит и приватные работают правильно.

Comment: @temq оо вот это кстати тоже хотел узнать, так как когда я генерирую тест класс то он предлагает добавить только публичные методы. Но тогда не совсем понятна логика, ведь может быть такое когда класс использует связку из приватных методов которые вызываются из `onCreate()` и в которых есть логика, что тогда их не тестировать? Вот так `onCreate() -> privat() (сложная логика) -> privat() (сложная логика) -> privat() (сложная логика)` такой класс по сути должен остаться без тестов, верно?

Comment: Ну результат же куда то отображается, не в пустую же они молотят. Можно вынести сложную логику в отдельный класс с публичным методом который возвращает результат и протестировать его. Вообще трудно тестировать когда бизнес. логика зашита в Activity/Fragment. Если использовать тот же mvp, то логику легко протестировать отдельно от ui. И стоит учитывать что нельзя просто так взять и протестировать любой код. Необходимо научится писать код который потом можно легко протестировать.

Comment: @temq как бы научиться писать такой код)) Ну я сейчас пробую перебрать то что написано и сделать чтоб соответствовало MVP думаю это облегчит понимание тестирования, а то сейчас как то не ясно получается)

Comment: Просто перед написанием думайте как это протестировать, ну и все приходит с опытом.

Comment: @temq чтоб понимать как это протестировать, нужно понимать как вообще тестировать) Я вот решил попробовать на своем приложении, но понимаю, что тут что то страшное происходит)) В общем сейчас буду пробовать)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko принцип test driven development на том и построен - вы пишите тест-класс, тестирующий еще не реализованную логику класса. Дальше реализуете логику так, чтобы она проходила тесты. При таком подходе ваши классы не будут сильно запутанными, так как иначе вы их не сможете протестировать. Многие считают эту методику сильно замедляющей разработку, но с другой стороны плюсы её очевидны когда проект нужно расширять и поддерживать. Так что пишите сначала тесты, а потом уже реализацию.